# SQL: convert 24-hour time to 12-hour time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a SQL report that tracks agent login and logout times. The request is to add a threshold to login time to track agents coming in late. I've separated the DATETIME field to be able to add the threshold, but now I only get 24-hour time instead of 12-hour time. Here's my query:

```
    SELECT Interval = CONVERT(char,AL.LogoutDateTime,101),
   Year = DATEPART(yy, AL.LogoutDateTime),
   Month = DATEPART(mm, AL.LogoutDateTime),
   Day = DATEPART(dd, AL.LogoutDateTime),
   Week = DATEPART(ww, AL.LogoutDateTime),
   DOY = DATEPART(dy, AL.LogoutDateTime),
   DOW = DATEPART(dw, AL.LogoutDateTime),
   A.EnterpriseName as AgentName,
    AL.LogoutDateTime,
    AL.LoginDuration,
    AL.Extension,
    AL.ReasonCode,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(s, -(AL.LoginDuration), AL.LogoutDateTime),101) AS LoginDate,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(s, -(AL.LoginDuration), AL.LogoutDateTime),8) AS LoginTime,
    A.SkillTargetID

    FROM
    Agent_Logout AL
    JOIN Agent A ON AL.SkillTargetID = A.SkillTargetID
    where LogoutDateTime between :start_date and :end_date
    and A.SkillTargetID IN (select SkillTargetID from Agent_Team_Member where AgentTeamID in 
    (:Agent))
    group by LogoutDateTime,
    EnterpriseName,
    LoginDuration,
    Extension,
    ReasonCode,
    A.SkillTargetID,
    DATEPART(yy, AL.LogoutDateTime),
    DATEPART(mm, AL.LogoutDateTime),
    DATEPART(dd, AL.LogoutDateTime),
    DATEPART(ww, AL.LogoutDateTime),
    DATEPART(dy, AL.LogoutDateTime),
    DATEPART(dw, AL.LogoutDateTime),
    CONVERT(char,AL.LogoutDateTime,101)

    order by EnterpriseName
```

Here are my results:

```
    Interval    Year    Month   Day Week    DOY DOW AgentName   LogoutDateTime          LoginDuration   Extension   LoginDate   LoginTime   
    05/27/2020  2020    5       27  22      148 4   Jane Doe    2020-05-27 12:43:53.227 7429     1234   05/27/20    14:40:04
```

I know the issue is the the LoginTime field that I create, but I can't figure out how to convert it back to standard time. If I leave the field DATETIME, I can't set login thresholds because the date keeps the threshold from working correctly...so how can I split the datetime field while maintaining the 12-hour time? Instead of `14:40:04` it would be `2:40:04 pm`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query uses product specific functions.)

Comment: Sorry...I guess I should have included that. SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18206.0

Comment: When you say ["military time" do you mean 24-hour time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-hour_clock#Military_time)? 14:40:04 instead of 2:40:04pm?

Comment: Correct. I'd like it to show AM/PM as opposed to 24 hour time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(s, -(AL.LoginDuration), AL.LogoutDateTime),8)
```

use

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), CAST(DATEADD(s, -(AL.LoginDuration), AL.LogoutDateTime) AS TIME),0)
```

It converts datetime to time (no date part), and then time to stardard format

Comment: Very very close...the only issue now is that since it is a string, I can't get the threshold to work.

Comment: You can use CAST(DATEADD(s, -(AL.LoginDuration), AL.LogoutDateTime) AS TIME) for filtering, it has type time: CAST(DATEADD(s, -(AL.LoginDuration), AL.LogoutDateTime) AS TIME) > '8:00'